# Adb shell commands are not working in php

Tags: php, adb, shell-exec

adb shell commands are not working in php but they are working in command prompt.

In window 7, I tried to execute 'adb devices' command via php as below. I also tried with shell_exec() and system(). But none of them are working. I ran 'ipconfig' command in php and it's working fine. It's just 'adb' that's not working.

```
<?php
exec('adb devices', $output);
echo '<pre>'.$output.'</pre>';
?>
```

I want it to return me the list of devices attached to the pc.

Answer (score 0):

the issue you have is connected to the PATH variable. This variable contains all paths where the shell tries to look for executables.

Your personal terminal should have configured the PATH variable to contain the absolute path to Android tools. Unfortunately, it's not shared with PHP runtime.

One of the solutions can be to use absolute executable path in your code:

```
exec('C:\any_path\Android-SDK\bin\adb devices', $output);
```

You can either make the PATH variable used by PHP process to contain the absolute path to Android tools.

Comment: I tried to give the absolute path as well but it's not working.

Comment: It's working now. There were permission issue. The server should have permission for accessing sdk tools directory. This helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640045/php-shell-exec-only-works-for-certain-commands